# Enterprise library integer output size with stored procedure

Tags: int, size, output, enterprise-library

i have the following code

```
 using (DbCommand cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand("asp"))
            {
                db.AddOutParameter(cmd, P_id, DbType.Int32, 0);
            }
```

its give me an error what the size should be ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have enough code....because I can't tell what P_id is.  (string, int, etc)

Having said that...I have working code that looks like this:

```
        DbCommand dbc = db.GetStoredProcCommand("dbo.uspMyProc");
        db.AddOutParameter(dbc, "@MyParameterName", DbType.Int32, 0);
```